# How to make CSS animations return to the original position smoothly

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I'm making my very first website and I'm trying to add some animations to my navbar links so their size and color change when I hover over them. The problem is that the animation works well but once I remove the curser, the elements return to their original styles instantly without being animated. I have searched for a solution but couldn't find anything that could actually fix this problem.

---

```css
.nav_links a {
  color: #342056;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}
.nav_links a:hover {
  animation: nav_elements_animation 0.5s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes nav_elements_animation {
  100% {
    color: #0d0220;
    text-decoration: underline;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    font-size: 1.3em;
  }
}
```

```html
 <nav>
        <div class="logo">
            <h4><a href="Index.html"><img src="Images/AbdoDevs.png" alt="AbdoDevs"></a></h4>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav_links">
            <li><a href="Index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#About">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Our_Projects">Our Projects</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Comment: you need transition here not animation

Comment: @TemaniAfif 
I have tried transition but the problem is that the transition is being applied to the element when the page is reloaded (when the page is reloaded the letter spacing is being transitioned to reach 2px and when I hover the curser it is transitioned again to reach 3px and same with colors)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve it like this.

```css
.nav_links a {
  color: #342056;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  transition: all .5s
}
.nav_links a:hover {
    color: #0d0220;
    text-decoration: underline;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    font-size: 1.3em;
}
}
```

```html
 <nav>
        <div class="logo">
            <h4><a href="Index.html"><img src="Images/AbdoDevs.png" alt="AbdoDevs"></a></h4>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav_links">
            <li><a href="Index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#About">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Our_Projects">Our Projects</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

`@keyframes` animations are not necessary for this. We just need to change the `font-size` and add the `transition` CSS property to the element to give the smoothness for the changes when `hover`. The more `ms` you give the transition, the smoother it becomes.

### Try the following snippet

```css
.nav_links a {
  color: #342056;
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  transition: 400ms;
}
.nav_links a:hover {
  font-size:1.5em;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="nav_links">
      <li><a href="Index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#About">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#Our_Projects">Our Projects</a></li>
      <li><a href="#Contact">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the `transition` command you can make the animation smooth

I would suggest this css code to be what you can use:

```
.nav_links a {
  color: #342056;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  transition: all 0.5s
}
.nav_links a:hover {
  animation: nav_elements_animation 0.5s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes nav_elements_animation {
  100% {
    color: #0d0220;
    text-decoration: underline;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    font-size: 1.3em;
  }
}
```

And the html code should remain same